# Entity framework Migration add new column to view

Tags: entity-framework, view

I have a view

```
[Table("View1")]
    public class View1Model
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
     }
```

I would like to add another public int Weight to the table because in the sql database i updated the view, however the migration wont work.

It says when i try to update database that

Cannot alter 'dbo.View1' because it is not a table.

I know that i can remove the 'table' attribute but that will not work because i need to check in my code.Out of the question

Answer (score 6):

When you `add-migration` it will try to `AddColumn()` in the `Up()` and `DropColumn()` in the `Down()`. You'll want to remove those lines from the migration and manually change the view with a `Sql(@"ALTER VIEW ...")` command in which you modify the view directly in SQL. This will accomplish what the automatic migration was trying to do.

Comment: There really is no automatic way to do this? Shouldn't EF realise it's a view, not a table and act accordingly?